# Subtraction of ordered Lists

Tags: c#, collections

How to calculate subtraction (set operation) of ordered lists in C#?

I am interesed in concise solution.

E.g. after execution of code:

```
List<int> a = new int[] { 1, 2, 5, 6, 7}.ToList();
List<int> b = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 6}.ToList();
List<int> c = ListSubtract(a, b);
```

`c` should contains `5, 7`.

It would be good to perform in `O(a.Count()+b.Count())` operations, but it is not critical.
Thanks.

Comment: What if `b` is longer than `a`? Is this is a set operation? Or does position matter?

Comment: set operation, updated question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the LINQ [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348938.aspx) operator.

```
List<int> c = a.Except(b).ToList();
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Generally speaking, if one has to do some manipulations with collections LINQ can handle the problem in 95% of cases.

Comment: @Oybek yes, but I have no a lot of experience with LINQ and not have habbit how to find better what I need. In fact I expected LINQ has something for me :)